# question related to UIColour

Tags: iphone

I have RGB for setting colour of my label

it is like this
R-:0
G:-78
B-255
and hash code is #004eff

can u tell me how to give this to my label as under below

UILabel *label;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIColor takes RGB values as a float between 0.0 and 1.0. To get that from a value between 0 and 255, you need to divide by 255.

```
[myLabel setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.0 green:78/255.0 blue:255/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
```

You may want to write a category method that does this for you, or even a simple preprocessor macro.